# VMware Virtual machine automation tools and methods

Tags: selenium, automation, virtual-machine

I'm new to VM automation however have used Selenium and Appium to extensively automate mobile devices.

I wanted to ask what kind of programs, tools to use for VM automation that allow you to access the VM GUI elements and move the mouse cursor even before entering the login screen similar to how Selenium allows you to?

so far I've only found "vmrun", but while helpful it doesn't seem to allow you to get displayed elements and move the mouse cursor around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions here:

1) Old style (I won't recommend it)
Using visually automation packages, one of them is autoit https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

It allows you to generate mouse movements, clicks, typing, etc. so you could access visually the vm gui.

2) Automate things programatically (this makes more sense):
Using the vm command line:
https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_learning_cli_vmrun.html

Comment: 1) Yes, before that I've found Sikuli and the reviews seem to be pretty good, so right now I have it as plan B, but still would be better to have something that allows to access elements not just visually. 2) I've seen before as mentioned in the post, but so far I haven't seen a way to move the mouse or get an element object back.

Comment: That's why I suggest to use the VM command line to access the functions programatically instead of the visual automation